# Get the first 4 words of a text line C#

Tags: c#

I have this text file which contains string lines like below.

```
iPhone 4S White 16GB MC920, MC924, MD237, MD239, MD277, MD378, MD866, ME805
iPhone 4S White 32GB MC921, MD244, MD279, MD380, MD246
iPhone 4S White 64GB MD260, MD271, MD272, MD281, MD382
```

What I want to achieve is, I want to read the lines and identify the line that has a specific model number(starts with M)

For instance,

If the model number is, MD378 I want to read the lines and find the line that has the model number and then get the first 4 words from that line. That means I should get the below words.

iPhone 
4S 
White
16GB

I'm using the below code to read the text file,

```
var fileStream = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\DvDB.ADB", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(""+Model_Number))
                {
                    //Need to perform the processing here.
                }
            }
        }
```

Appreciate if I could know how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it is always 4 words and that each word is separated by a space character, you can use `string.split` to achieve this.

```
    var fileStream = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\DvDB.ADB", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(""+Model_Number))
            {
                //Need to perform the processing here.
                string[] lineArray = line.Split(' ').Take(4).ToArray();
                //Each word is assumed to be separated by a space character
                //Array now contains the first 4 words from the line.
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Take first four words from a line

```
var firstFourWords = streamReader.ReadLine()
    .Split(' ')    // Split line by whitespace
    .Take(4)       // Take first four words from the array
    .ToList();     // Optionally convert to List<string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost does it - it reads through the file line-by-line and identifies the line containing the substring, all you need to do is the last bit.

The most succinct way would be to use `String.Split` on whitespace and then join the first 4 non-empty elements - but if a line is very long then `String.Split` becomes suboptimal (because it would be allocating new strings beyond the 4th word).

```
return
    String.Join(
        line.Split( null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
        .Take( 4 )
    ), " " );
```

- `line.Split( null, RemoveEmptyEntries )` will split the string on every whitespace character and returns `String[]`, though this is inefficient for long strings with many elements.
- `String[]` is also `IEnumerable<String>` so it can be used with Linq's `.Take(n)` extension method to return an `IEnumerable<String>` consisting of the first 4 (or fewer) elements.
- Finally, `String.Join( IEnumerable<String>, String )` is used to join the first 4 words back together into a single string.

A more efficient approach would scan the line for the 4th word break and generate a substring accordingly:

```
int word4Idx = -1;
int word = 0;
bool inWS = true;
for(int i = 0; i < line.Length && word < 4; i++) {

    if( inWS ) {
        if( !Char.IsWhitespace( line[i] ) ) {
            word++;
            word4IDx = i;
            inWS = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        inWS = Char.IsWhitespace( line[i] );
    }

}

if( word4Idx > -1 && word4Idx < line.Length ) return line.Substring( 0, word4Idx );
return line;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
var fileStream = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\DvDB.ADB", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(""+Model_Number))
                {
                   var arr = line.split(' ');
                   Array.Resize(ref arr, 4);
                   string 4words = string.Join(" ", arr);
                }
            }
        }
```